# Retrieving low level elements from complex list (R)

Tags: r, list, command

Suppose you have the following rather complex list structure:

```
all_m<-list();clist1<-list();clist2<-list()
for (j in 1:3){ for (i in 1:5){
      m1<-matrix(rnorm(4,0,1),2,2)
      m2<-matrix(rnorm(9,0,1),3,3)
      m3<-matrix(rnorm(16,0,1),4,4)
      m4<-matrix(rnorm(25,0,1),5,5)
      all_m<-list(m1,m2,m3,m4)
      names(all_m)<-c('m1','m2','m3','m4')
      clist1[[i]]<-all_m
      clist2[[j]]<-clist1
    }}
```

How can I address and retrive all low level elements in `clist2` that are of the same type, say `$m2`, and re-arrange  them into an array?

I guess this is possible without at loop. I would be interested in a solution that uses one of R's control structures, indexing or alike.

Comment: what's `clist1`, `clist2`?  where is `list2`? Why don't you give us `dput(list2)` instead? That will help us to help you better.

Comment: I forgot to paste the first line of the example. Please see the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
library(abind)
fun1 <- function(x) abind(lapply(x,'[[',"m2"),along=3)
abind(lapply(clist2,fun1),along=4)
```